# Laplace Transform of the Unit Step Function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Finding the Laplace transform of:

$$f(t) = \begin{cases}1 ,& 0 \leq t < 1 \\t^2 ,& 1 \leq t \leq 2 \\ 4, & t \ge 2\end{cases}$$

Heaviside /Unit step function: $$1+ (t^2 -1)u(t-1) + (4-t^2)u(t-2)$$

The Laplace transform of it is:

$$\mathcal{L}{(1)} = 1/s$$
$$\mathcal{L}{(t^2 -1)u(t-1)} = e^{-s} \mathcal{L}{f(t)} = e^{-s} \mathcal{L}{(t^2)} = e^{-s}\frac {2}{s^3}$$
$$\mathcal{L}{(4 - t^2)u(t-2)} = e^{-2s} \mathcal{L}{f(t)} = e^{-2s} \mathcal{L}{(??)} =...$$

Could someone verify if first of all my equation is right and how do I take the Laplace transform of the last equation.

Comment: $\mathcal{L}[4 - t^2] = \mathcal{L}[4] - \mathcal{L}[t^2] = 4/s - 2/s^3$, as the Laplace transform is linear. Incidentally, the second transform you have written above is incorrect, it ignores the $-1$ .

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Looking at the equation for Laplace transform, your answer can't be right.

Comment: And why is that?

Comment: For clarity's sake, simply try calculating the laplace transform of the box function supported on $[0,1]$. What do you get?